# Quickly: Logging from Python application

Tags: python, quickly, logging

Consider the following truncated source file (an empty Quickly application with unnecessary lines stripped):

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('foobar')

class FoobarWindow(Window):
    __gtype_name__ = "FoobarWindow"

    def finish_initializing(self, builder): # pylint: disable=E1002
        """Set up the main window"""
        super(FoobarWindow, self).finish_initializing(builder)

        # Code for other initialization actions should be added here.
        logger.info("hello world from the logger")
```

The whole code is already in the quickly template, only the call to `logger.info` has been added. But I don't see any console output and I have not seen any logfile. Could somebody elaborate on logging practice in applications created with Quickly? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)` after the import statement.

This will make all log messages  being redirected to the terminal. In terms of practices, i think there's nothing specific to Quickly. If you need to tweak other parameters (log to a file instead of console, log format, etc) you can find more info [here](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html). Hope it helps.